# How to send data from angular 8 to spring boot through REST API

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, angular8

I want to send my name through textbox from Angular 8 to Spring boot through REST API. If name is "admin" then spring boot should validate it and "Welcome" msg should be display on Angular page. If not "admin" Bye msg should be display.